# Passing MAVEN_OPTS in Pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to convert a free-style job to pipeline code. following are the MAVEN_OPTS got declared along with maven goals under "Invoke Artifactory Maven 3" in job.

Maven Goals: clean install

MAVEN_OPTS: -Xmx2048m

-Xms512m

-XX:PermSize=256m

-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

-Denv.build-timestamp=${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}

-Denv.build-job=${JOB_NAME}

-Denv.build-number=${BUILD_NUMBER}

-Denv.build-url=${BUILD_URL}

-Denv.git-commit=${GIT_COMMIT}

-Denv.git-branch=${GIT_BRANCH}

**My trial in pipeline:**

```
node('node1') {

    def javaHome = tool name: 'JDK 1.8', type: 'hudson.model.JDK'
    def mvnHome = tool name: 'M3', type: 'hudson.tasks.Maven$MavenInstallation'
    sh "$mvnHome/bin/mvn -f pom.xml clean install -U -Dmaven.repo.local=$WORKSPACE/.m2/repository -Xmx2048m -Xms512m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dtimestamp=${BUILD_TIMESTAMP} ..."

    }

Error:
Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local
```

I'm sure that I'm passing MAVEN_OPTS in a wrong way. Can someone guide me the right systax to declare MAVEN_OPTS in Pipeline

Answer (score 8):

You can set the `mavenOpts` in the `withMaven` call in a pipeline `stage`:

```
node('node1') {

    stage ('MavenGoals') {  
        withMaven(jdk: 'JDK 1.8', 
                maven: 'M3', 
                mavenLocalRepo: '$WORKSPACE/.m2/repository', 
                mavenOpts: '-Xmx2048m -Xms512m -XX:PermSize=256m ....') {      
            sh 'mvn clean install'    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Set environment variable MAVEN_OPTS and it will work.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        jdk 'JDK 1.8'
        maven 'M3'
    }
    environment {
        MAVEN_OPTS = ' -Denv.build-timestamp=${BUILD_TIMESTAMP} ...'
    }
    stage('Example') {
        steps {
            sh 'mvn clean install'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't check it but I found a solution mentioning maven_opts within the withMaven() environment. Let me post it.